# Google maps zoom

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I use Dell Venue 7 tablet. The app is written on phonegap. After 18x zoom this app stops respond on any requests.

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas[0], {
    zoom: 2,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(40, -79),
    zoomControl: true,
    zoomControlOptions: {
        style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL,
    },
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
        style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR,
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_RIGHT
    },
    scaleControl: true,
    streetViewControl: false,
    preserveViewport: true
});
```

and that i do `map.setZoom(18)` and the app stops working.

Comment: zoom of 18 is about the maximum limit for many places. Some cities go up to 20 and a few places go as far as 23. So is it just possible that the location you're zooming to only goes up to level 18?  You may want to look at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maxzoom to find out the maximum zoom level available to you

Comment: I don't remember `preserveViewport` being a valid option for a `Map` object.

Comment: Zoom works well on other devices like iPhone, Jiayu, Lenovo. But the app stops working on Dell even with 12x zoom for 3-5 minutes, and then "restores". May the problem be because of device feeble processor?

Comment: @gpgekko That's right. But I doubt this is the cause of the issue. Anyway you should remove that parameter.

Comment: I've written the code which will approach max zoom which is allowed for direct location. Eventually the app stops working with 12x-18x zoom. Also I removed the preserveView point setting.

Comment: Show us how you're calling `setZoom` - it's in response to a user event, you're doing it in a timed loop, ...?

Comment: No, I've simply made the button with function `map.setZoom(18)` for test.